# How to test an SpringBoot aspect method with JUnit?

Tags: java, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-boot-test

I use Springboot and I want test my new custom annotation by JUnit.

My original code with my `@CronLogger` custom annotation on `importData` method:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class ImportTask {
  @Async
  @Scheduled(cron = "${import}")
  @SchedulerLock(name = "import")
  @CronLogger()
  public void importData() {
    ...
  }
}
```

**My custom annotation:**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface CronLogger {
 
}
```

**My custom Aspect method:**

```
@Aspect
@Component
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class CronLoggerAspect {
    
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CronLoggerAspect.class);
    
    @Around("@annotation(CronLogger)")
    public Object trace(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("CronLogger");
        log.debug("CronLogger");
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

**My JUnit test:**

```
@Slf4j
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@Import(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.class) // activate aspect
class ImportTaskTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private ImportTask importTask;

    @Test
    void importData() throws JSchException, SftpException, SftpTransfertException {
        // execute test
        importTask.importData();
    }

}
```

the result is OK but whitout execute Aspect method code.

Comment: If you are using runtime weaving, hope you started your tests with the `-javaagent:<path-to-aspectjweaver-jar>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("sit")
class TaskTest {

    @Autowired
    private TaskService taskService;

    @Test
    void testCronLoggerSuccess() throws CronException {
        taskService.testCronLogger("test Success");
        ...
    }
}
```

Nota: `@ActiveProfiles("sit")` use for H2 database.